# Context in a baseAdapter class

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-context

Is there a way to get the `context` in a `BaseAdapter` class with `getApplicationContext()`?

I need this, because i'm going to load images from url's. Here I'm using `context`:

This is in a class that extends `BaseAdapter`

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: pass it in constructor of a custom baseadapter

Comment: You can pass the Context using an overloaded constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it in the constructor when you extend/implement:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SomeBaseAdapter{
  private final Context mcontext;

  public MyAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass reference to the Context in the adapters constructor and store it or you can directly reference it from parent in method `getView()`

```
public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     //inflate layout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to instantiate a variable to bring the context content like this:

In the getView()
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemtutor, null);

And create a context variable:
Context mycontext = view.getContext();